# Read csv file to datatable and pass to stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a csv file that has 80+ columns and 3000+ rows. My columns are all in the header (name1name2name3name4) which is fine. my error is that it is not counting all my rows and adding it to the database.. I want my stream reader or whatever other recommended header to skip the first record since its filled with columns names. then add the data rows.

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename))
            {
                //this assume the first record is filled with the column names

                    string[] headers = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
                    foreach (string header in headers)
                    {
                        tvp.Columns.Add(header);
                    }
                    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        string[] rows = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
                        //Create a new row
                        DataRow dr = tvp.NewRow();
                        for (int i = 0; i < headers.Length; i++)
                        {
                            dr[i] = rows[i];
                        }
                        tvp.Rows.Add(dr);
                       // Console.WriteLine(tvp);
                    }               
            }

            //Passing a Table-Valued Parameter to a Stored Procedure
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Connectionstring))
            {
                con.Open();
                //Execute the cmd
                // Configure the command and sql parameter. 
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.DataTable", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 5000;

                // Create a DataTable with the modified rows.  
                DataTable addedCategories = tvp.GetChanges(DataRowState.Added);
                // these next lines are important to map the C# DataTable object to the correct SQL User Defined Type
                SqlParameter tvparam = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt", tvp);
                tvparam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
                tvparam.TypeName = "dbo.DataTableType";
                //SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("@dt", SqlDbType.Structured)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fy", drlFY.SelectedValue);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@offid", drlOfficeID.SelectedValue);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@updateBy", "9999");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sourcefile", strSrcFile);

                // Execute the command
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
```

Comment: Did you know that SQL Server has a bulk importer?  Also `String.Split` is a terrible, error prone way to process a CSV

Comment: When you're adding your columns to tvp, give them a type other than the default (string)?

Comment: @WelcomeOverflow my problem is that it is not adding the values to the sql table.

Comment: @CaiusJard I am unsure how to do that. I just need to add these values from the datable to the stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear about your specific requirement with respect to data import from CSV file but bulk import is an option for you. Check it out at : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-bulk-data-by-using-bulk-insert-or-openrowset-bulk-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017